# Inheriting handles with ShellExecuteEx

Tags: windows, winapi, shellexecute, shellexecuteex

`CreateProcess` has `bInheritHandles` parameter that allows inheritable handles to be inherited by new process.

Does `ShellExecuteEx` provides such possibility? Especially with `runas` verb.

Comment: in case you use `runas` verb `CreateProcessAsUser` called from `appinfo.AiLaunchProcess` and `bInheritHandles` hardcoded to be `FALSE` unconditionally. so - no way

Comment: Maybe try  [`CreateProcessElevated()`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19165/Vista-UAC-The-Definitive-Guide) instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I have already read this article, but I'm however disappointed with presented solution. Well, I guess it's obviously to create new elevated process and then use `CreateProcess` from it.

Comment: Sounds much like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does ShellExecuteEx provides such possibility?

No, it does not.

Comment: There's very little more to be said given the question. It's a simple yes/no and the answer is no. There will be a solution to your problem, but your current approach isn't going to work out. If you want advice for the underlying problem you'd need to ask a question about that problem.